# Failing to foam/cream milk in a freddo cappuccino

Tags: milk, foamed-milk, cappuccino

I'm desperately trying, and failing, to make a freddo cappuccino for my wife.  Specifically, I cannot for the life of me get the milk to the right texture.  Please watch the below video (whole video and milk pour both independently linked for the impatient)

I can froth milk using a frother (machine with disk at bottom) but the texture that you're going for is almost creamed, at least thickened?

In most videos they use a stirrer / mixer (milkshake machine for lack of better words) which I own.  No matter what I do it just comes out as bubbly milk.  I've read online use non fat, full fat, and everything in between.  Does anyone recognize the texture I'm looking for?  How can I achieve it?

[Link to whole video](https://youtu.be/htrbw3tIKXs)

[Link to milk pour](https://youtu.be/htrbw3tIKXs?t=325)

Comment: You're not giving us very much information on your own process. It's hard to tell what might be wrong without knowing what you're doing.

Comment: Many freddo recipes tell you to blend the coffee with ice. That would produce a kind of froth in the coffee itself which might contribute to the texture you want. Some cappuccino freddo recipes also suggest using unfrothed milk, which would work well if you blend coffee with ice because the coffee froth will mix with the milk when you pour. Try using a spoon when you pour your milk to make a layered drink. Lastly, a milkshake machine won't make good froth. Try searching Amazon for a frothing wand and try that. It'll work a lot better.

Comment: @NelsAbrams see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ultra-high-temperature_processing).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I continued experimenting and figured out the milk was what was problematic.  I switched from HTST pasteurization to UHT and the milk cold frothed in seconds just like the video.